# How do I extract subsets from a dataframe based on a datetime column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with the following structure.

I would like to select the data in the text column in chunks of two weeks, based upon the datetime column.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

```
     text_column        datetime_column
0      jfklsjf        2014-05-10 22:42:35
1      ldjskfj        2014-05-14 03:04:24
2      dslffkf        2014-07-03 23:05:17
.         .                     .
.         .                     .
```

Comment: try: [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for specific chunks, you can do just a normal filter using pandas

```
df[(df['datetime_colum']>='2014-04-10') & (df['datetime_column']<'2014-05-10')]
```

My example there will get you just the days that are for october 4th 2014. You can change the dates to get more days, if you don't already before doing this make sure the datetime column is an pandas datetime column. You can do this by

```
df['datetime_column']= pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_column'])
```

Comment: Yeah it's really the more general case where I pull rows in batches of two weeks that I'm struggling with. Thanks though!

Comment: random batches?

Comment: Each row in the batch should stay in the same order.