# select rows from a datetime column with pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, slice

I hava a dataframe with many columns, one of which (receivedtime) has been properly converted to datetime

```
id   receivedtime   
1    2020-09-08 00:35:12  
2    2020-09-09 06:16:09  
3    2020-09-10 12:47:04
4    2020-09-08 15:57:05
```

and so on. I want to select only those from a given day (this is similar to this post:[subsets from a datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55619303/how-do-i-extract-subsets-from-a-dataframe-based-on-a-datetime-column/55619832), which helps but dont work for me). I have tried to do a simple substetting:

```
df[df["receivedtime"]=="2020-09-10"]
```

but I got an empty dataframe in return. I believe it has to do with the hours minutes and seconds.Obviously one way is to strip that info from datetime, but I want to preserve the whole structure. I even tried using dt.datetime but nothing seems to work. What is wrong in here?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `receivedtime` is not always a sharp date, i.e. having time equal to `00:00:00`. Try, for example, `dt.normalize()` to get the dates from the timestamp:

```
 df[df["receivedtime"].dt.normalize()=="2020-09-10"]
```

Output:

```
   id        receivedtime
2   3 2020-09-10 12:47:04
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below to convert your datetime to date

```
df[pd.to_datetime(df["receivedtime"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')=="2020-09-10"]
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a DataFrame "new" by splitting the date at a whitespace

```
new = df["receivedtime"].str.split(" ", expand = True)
new
```

> output

```
             0        1
0    2020-09-08 00:35:12  
1    2020-09-09 06:16:09  
2    2020-09-10 12:47:04  
3    2020-09-08 15:57:05
```

Then use the boolean masking

```
df[new[0]=="2020-09-08"]
```

Output:

```
    receivedtime
0   2020-09-08 00:35:12
3   2020-09-08 15:57:05
```

You will get all the dates with time